# Make overlay menu slide from top down

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a navigation for the site I'm building that currently slides in as an overlay from the left. What I'm trying to do, though, is get it to slide in from the top.

Below is the current CSS and JS for the menu specifically. I feel like it's simple to rotate where the menu comes in from, but I just can't figure it out.

**CSS**

```
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: rgba(0,162,85,.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}

    .sidenav a {
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 25px;
        color: #f1f1f1;
        display: block;
        transition: 0.3s;

    }

        .sidenav a:hover {
            color: lightgray;
              opacity: 1;
        }


.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 355px;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var menuItems = [
    {
        name: "HowToQuit",
        openFunction: "openHow()",
        closeFunction: "closeHow()",
        state: false //closed
    },
    {
        name: "StayingQuit",
        openFunction: "openStay()",
        closeFunction: "closeStay()",
        state: false
    },
    {
        name: "FactsAndMyths",
        openFunction: "openFacts()",
        closeFunction: "closeFacts()",
        state: false
    }
];


function openHow() {
    document.getElementById("howtoquitnav").style.width = "100%";
    document.getElementById("howtoquitnav").style.maxWidth = "1046px";
}

function closeHow() {
    document.getElementById("howtoquitnav").style.width = "0";
}

function openStay() {
    document.getElementById("stayquit").style.width = "100%";
    document.getElementById("stayquit").style.maxWidth = "1046px";
}

function closeStay() {
    document.getElementById("stayquit").style.width = "0";
}

function openFacts() {
    document.getElementById("factsmyths").style.width = "100%";
    document.getElementById("factsmyths").style.maxWidth = "1046px";
}

function closeFacts() {
    document.getElementById("factsmyths").style.width = "0";
}

function handleMenuItem(menuItemName) {
    for (var i = 0; i < menuItems.length; i++) {
        if (menuItems[i].name === menuItemName && !menuItems[i].state) {
            var open = new Function(menuItems[i].openFunction);
            open();
            menuItems[i].state = true;
        } else {
            var close = new Function(menuItems[i].closeFunction);
            close();
            menuItems[i].state = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use jQuery (or not against it), you can easily achieve that with .animate function.

Comment: It would help if you can include your HTML also.

Comment: @SamuilPetrov I didn't even think of JQuery. When and used the slide toggle and it worked perfectly!